# How can I get this effect and what is it called?

Tags: trim

In the photograph the machine has a silver edge on the outer panels, but I have seen it in all colours.

How can I achieve the same effect with my panels?

[image: Chrome banded arcade machine]

<sup>Image from [Costco.co.uk](http://www.costco.co.uk/view/p/arcade-overload-classic-upright-arcade-machine-159031)</sup>

Comment: Are you asking about the face of the side panels or the edges?

Comment: I'm talking about the silver trim around the edge of the outer panels.

Comment: I don't know but I'm pretty sure I remember in the old days those were an applied metal strip that was chrome plated. They were partly for looks but they would have also greatly improved the bump resistance of the edges. These days if it's a metal strip it could be polished stainless steel or aluminium but going by the lack of visible rivets I think it's also possible that it could be some foil-finished plastic edging material that is glued in place.

Answer (score 7):

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=metallic+edge+banding&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) for "metalic edge banding" comes up with several options.

There is the flat, [glue on](https://edgecoinc.com/metallic/) style that goes on like any other wood based edging:

[image: https://edgecoinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/metallic.png]
<sup>From edgecoinc.com</sup>

There is also aluminum (or other metal) [T-rail](https://www.aluminumsys.com/edge-banding-for-cabinet-doors-aluminum-edge-banding-metal-edge-banding-for-cabinet-do/) style that presses into a slot routed or cut into the edge of the piece:

[image: https://www.aluminumsys.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/BRW-11.jpg]
<sup>from aluminumsys.com</sup>

Note: Not affiliated with either company, just the first couple of examples I found.

Comment: I would avoid the aluminum option.  It is too stiff to readily install around the small radius corners without some serious and iffy snipping of the web (the upright in the T).  Additionally, its price is about 15 times that of the plastic T sections shown in @Matt's answer.

Comment: Valid points, @AstPace. The critical portion of the answer is the first line. The rest was (mostly) to avoid a link-only answer... :) On the other hand, if you need some _sturdy_ protection, I think the AL version would hold up to quite a bit more abuse.

Comment: Yep.  If you can only manage the tight corners.

Answer (score 6):

A cursory search comes up with T-Moulding. Knowing that I can then find pseudo chrome T-moulding for arcade cabinets. Not advocating any particular product but showcasing an example. The one pictured in your question is *likely* plastic to help it conform to the curves of the case however I could be wrong.

[image]

<sup>Image from a [eBay search result](http://www.ebay.com/bhp/arcade-t-molding)</sup>

Should be easy enough to install by using a slot cutter and a router.

[image]

<sup>Image from a [Rockler.com](http://www.rockler.com/power-tool-accessories/router-bits/slot-cutting-router-bits)</sup>

[You can look at a blog post about a user doing just that.](http://www.coldbeamgames.com/blog/i-built-an-arcade-cabinet)

Comment: copycat, but faster. :)

Comment: @AstPace I picked the example on appearance. Surely you can get metal as well. Likely the one in the OPs picture is the same. I will update to enforce that.